# There is an initial value problem: $x' = (2 \sqrt{|x|} + x^2)(3 - t)$. I need to proof that there is a solution going to infinity in finite time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

There is an initial value problem:

$x' = (2 \sqrt{|x|} + x^2)(3 - t)$

$x(0) = 0$

Proof there is a solution going to infinity in finite time. Is there an instable, non-negative, global solution?

---

So I wanted to solve that by:

$x' = (2 \sqrt{|x|} + x^2)(3 - t) \iff \frac{dx}{dt} = (2 \sqrt{|x|} + x^2)(3 - t) \iff \frac{dx}{2 \sqrt{|x|} + x^2} = (3 - t) dt $

But it turns out it's not an option since the integral of $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{|x|} + x^2}$ is something crazy. So there must be some other way to solve that by analyzing the initial equation.

If I had my general solution I would take "time" as a parameter $t \in [0, \infty)$. I would need to show that there exists a $t_0 \in [0, \infty )$ such that $x(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to t_0$.

I don't know how to do the other part of the exercise (with an instable, non-negative, global solution).

---

Edit 1 (Idea of @KBS):
Changing variable $x = y^2$ I get:

$x = y^2$

$x' = 2y y'$

$x' = (2 \sqrt{|x|} + x^2)(3 - t) \iff 2y y' = (2 y + y^4)(3 - t) \iff y' = (1 + \frac{y^3}{2})(3 - t) \iff \frac{dy}{dt} = (1 + \frac{y^3}{2})(3 - t) \iff \frac{dy}{1 + \frac{y^3}{2}} = (3 - t)dt$

And again, I get some crazy integral of $\int \frac{1}{1 + \frac{y^3}{2}} dy$

Comment: Have you tried the change of variable $x=y^2$ to get rid of the square root?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately, I don't think it works. I edited my original post - maybe I made some mistake.

Comment: You will need to be bit more persisting. The solution is not all the time immediate and you will need to continue thinking about it. The structure of the equation is much nicer now. Now you can try to find another system, called a comparison system, which both gives a lower bound for $y$ and exhibits a finite escape time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proving the existence of a finite escape time, consider the system

$$\dot{z}(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}3-t,&&\mathrm{if\ }t\in[0,t_1],\\
(3-t)(1+z(t)^2),&&\mathrm{if\ }t\in[t_1,3],
\end{array}\right.$$ where $z(0)=0$ and $t_1=3-\sqrt{5}>0$.

I claim that $y(t)\ge z(t)$ for all $t$ (where I am considering that the functions may take $\infty$ as a value after possible escape times).

Note first that we have $$\dot{y}(t)-\dot{z}(t)=(3-t)y(t)^3/2\ge0$$ over $t\in[0,t_1]$ and therefore we have that $y(t)\ge z(t)$ over that same interval.

Evaluating $z(t)$ at $t=t_1$ yields $z(t_1)=2$ and we have that

$$\dot{y}(t)-\dot{z}(t)=(3-t)(y(t)^3/2-z(t)^2).$$

We have that $y(t_1)\ge 2$ and, therefore, $y(t_1)^3/2-z(t_1)^2\ge0$. This implies that $y(t)\ge z(t)$ also on that interval.

Solving for $z(t)$, we have that $z(t)=t^2/3-3t$ for all $t\in[0,t_1]$. For the second fragment, we note that the differential equation can be rewritten as

$$\dfrac{dz}{1+z^2}=(3-s)ds$$

where I am using the change of variables $s=t$ for technical reasons. Then we can integrate both sides as

$$\int_{z(t_1)}^{z(t)}\dfrac{dz}{1+z^2}=\int_{t_1}^t(3-s)ds$$

which is equivalent to

$$\left[\arctan(z)\right]_{z(t_1)}^{z(t)}=\left[-\dfrac{1}{2}s^2+3s\right]_{t_1}^{t}$$

and finally leads to

$$\arctan(z(t))=\arctan(2)-t^2/2+3t+t_1^2/2-3t_1,\ t\in[t_1,3]$$

where I have used $z(t_1)=2$.

We have a finite escape-time for $z$ if there is a $t_2>t_1$ such that the right hand side is equal to $\pi/2$. Solving numerically for that $t_2$ yields $t_2=0.9819$.

Since the original system is bounded from above by a system that has a finite escape-time, then the original system must have a finite escape-time which is less than $t_2$. Better approximations can be obtained by using tighter comparison systems.

Comment: I don't understand the second interval. Why is $y' \geq z'$ if $3 - t$ can be negative? Also whay we know about values of $z(t)^2$?

Comment: @mathman12 The interval for the second one is at $[t_1,3]$ at most. Regarding your second question, I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Assuming that $z(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}−3t$ is the solution - I dont see it blowing out anywhere in the first interval. That function for $t_2$ returns finite value.

Comment: This is the first portion of the function where the function does not blow-up. It does blow-up soon after $t_1$.

Comment: Ok! Now I get it! Could you just describe how did you solve the second part getting $arctan(z(t))=arctan(2)−t^2/2+3t+t^2_1/2−3t_1$? I don't know why there is $arctan(2)$ and $t^2_1/2−3t_1$. I mean, I get just $arctan(z(t))−t^2/2+3t = C$

Comment: I have added more details.